# Как запустить таймер только при входе на сайт?

Tags: javascript

Это скрипт таймера обратного отсчета. Когда пользователь переходит на другую страницу, таймер начинает отсчет с начала. Мне нужно, чтобы таймер запускался только тогда, когда заходят на сайт, но при переходе на другие страницы, отсчет не начинался заново, а продолжался.

JS:

```
window. onload= function () {
    var i = 66;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        i--;
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 'Осталось: ' + i;
        if (i == 0) {
            document.getElementById('example').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'none';
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="timer"></div>
    <div id="example" style=" display: none; ">
    Привет
    </div>
```

Comment: Вам придется хранить значение таймера в сессии, и при загрузке каждой страницы ставить `var i=[значение сессии];`

Comment: Не надо сессии, хранить время нужно в куках или локал сторадже.

Answer (score 2):

Сохранять текущее `i` при каждом отсчете в куки, локальном хранилище, или же сессиях, если важно, чтобы при закрытии вкладки сбрасывать отсчет

И при старте отсчета проверять, было ли записано записано значение, если да - начинать отсчет от `i` равном записанному ранее, или от 66, как в вашем случае

```
window. onload= function () {

var local_val = localStorage.getItem("timer");
var i;

if(local_val)
   i = local_val ;
else 
   i = 66;

var timer_elem = document.getElementById('timer');
var example_elem = document.getElementById('example');

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        i--;
        timer_elem .innerHTML = 'Осталось: ' + i;
        localStorage.setItem("timer",i);
        if (i == 0) {
            example_elem.style.display = 'block';
            timer_elem .style.display = 'none';
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```